# Rebuilding local SVN repository from working copy

Tags: svn

I've been working on a project with a local SVN repository in Dropbox, but its revision history appears to have been corrupted beyond repair, and all checkins are failing now.  So I'm looking at creating a new repository from the existing working copy.  I'm okay with losing the history, so long as I can keep the actual paths in my development environments the same (on both my Mac and Windows dev machines).

Of course, if I just try to use `svn import` to import the local files...  svn doesn't recognise the existing paths as a working copy, it will force me to check them back out, thus changing the location of everything.

I've tried creating an empty `trunk/Client` folder in the new empty repository and checking that out to my existing `<main dev folder>/Client` directory, so that I can re-add all the items to it...  but the SVN client refuses to add the contents of `<main dev folder>/Client`, because it detects that they're already under version control from the old repository.

Plus of course, even if I do get them all checked in on my Mac dev machine, I'll need to pull a similar switch to get the Windows dev machine to sync its working copy from the new repository.  (I'm using svnX on the Mac and TortoiseSVN on Windows -- but I'm working from the Mac client because that working copy is the up-to-date one.)

Any suggestions on how to get these files into a new repository without having to rearrange everything?

(Note:  "give up on svn and move to git" is actually a fairly acceptable answer, but I'll still need guidance; my experience in both is equally limited!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You **must** to use [`svn import`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html) properly, because this command "commit an unversioned file or tree into the repository" and you *have* to prepare unversioned tree from your WC before import
2. Every Working Copy is linked to single repository and this relation stored in WC's metadata, which you **must** to change in order to link *old WC* and *new repo* with [`svn relocate`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html) command
3. In order to successfully relocate your WC to new repo, you **must** to provide for the new repository the same UUID, as it was in old repository with [`svnadmin setuuid`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.setuuid.html)

Thus

### Your long migration path

- Create unversioned copy of your WC
- Create new local empty repository (I'll recommend to prepare and use svnserve for `svn://` access-type, not `file:///` from the first steps)
- Get UUID of old repo (`svn info | grep UUID` in WC) and apply it to new repo
- Import tree from unversioned copy into new repo (to the same relative path, as it was in the old repo)
- Relocate your existing WC to new repository
- Try `svn up` to verify results

but you can prefer to forgot about old repo at all and use

### Your short path

- Create unversioned copy of your WC
- Create new local empty repository (I'll recommend to prepare and use svnserve for `svn://` access-type, not `file:///` from the first steps)
- Import tree from unversioned copy into new repo
- Test results of import with `svn ls -R <REPO-ROOT-URL>`
- Delete|archive old WC and checkout new WC to the old location from new repository

Comment: Thanks -- I'll give this a try in the next couple of days.  One question first:  what about ignored files?  There are build folders in the working-copy tree which were ignored or never added to the old repository.  If I export an unversioned copy of the working-copy, will this skip the ignored files?  Or do I need to set a global ignore list before doing the `svn import` command, or to import only specified subfolders?

Comment: @user1371844 - AFAICR, only import subtrees, because svn import (2 years ago) work with the whole tree from root

Comment: OK, I've followed the long migration path; it relocates to the new repository successfully.  But when I try to `svn update`, I get:  `svn: E160006: No such revision 65`.  This is because the newly imported repository is only at revision 2, where the old one was at revision 65. But even if I specify `svn up -r2`, I still get the `No such revision 65` message.  At this point should I just clobber the `.svn` directory in the working copy and check out again?

Comment: @user1371844 - just idea: create dump of repo, edit it's rev-ids by hand and import dump back (can't test, have not SVN now)